# How to print the values from a xml and write to a text file using : Seperator

Tags: xml, shell, xml-parsing, tags, text-files

```
I have a pom.xml, which i need to parse using shell to get the tag values and write it in to text file using ':' as a seperator

**XML:**
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.dtd</groupId>
      <artifactId>dtc-api-commons</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.dtd</groupId>
      <artifactId>dtc-api-commons</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1_1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.dtd</groupId>
      <artifactId>dtc-api-commons</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.dtd</groupId>
      <artifactId>dtc-api-commons</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

**Expected output:**
com.dtd:dtc-api-commons:3.3.2-SNAPSHOT
com.dtd:dtc-api-commons:3.3.1-SNAPSHOT
com.dtd:dtc-api-commons:3.3.1_1-SNAPSHOT
com.dtd:dtc-api-commons:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Please help me in providing the exact shell command to parse xml and write values in the expected format using : seperator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you enclose your XML within a root tag, likely `<project>` for a POM file:

```
<project>
    <dependency>
              <groupId>com.dtd</groupId>
              <artifactId>dtc-api-commons</artifactId>
              <version>3.3.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
              <groupId>com.dtd</groupId>
              <artifactId>dtc-api-commons</artifactId>
              <version>3.3.1_1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
              <groupId>com.dtd</groupId>
              <artifactId>dtc-api-commons</artifactId>
              <version>3.3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
              <groupId>com.dtd</groupId>
              <artifactId>dtc-api-commons</artifactId>
              <version>3.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</project>
```

You can use xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '//project/dependency' -v 'concat(groupId,":",artifactId,":",version)' -nl pom.xml
com.dtd:dtc-api-commons:3.3.2-SNAPSHOT
com.dtd:dtc-api-commons:3.3.1_1-SNAPSHOT
com.dtd:dtc-api-commons:3.3.1-SNAPSHOT 
com.dtd:dtc-api-commons:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT
```

`sel`: select
`-T`: outputs text
`-t`: template
`-m`: match the xpath
`-v`: get the value of all 3 nodes concatenated with `:`
`-nl`:  prints a newline